# How to verify certain text is displayed on the page/element?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath, textarea

I'm trying to capture screenshots using selenium webdriver on a page that has textarea with a large scrollable text. I need to capture screenshots of all the texts in the textarea. With my code, I am able to scroll down on the textarea and take screenshots but need to stop once all the texts are shown. Here is the code

```
    while(!textDisplayedInPage("text at the bottom of textarea element")){
        takeScreenShot();
        scrollDown();
       }
    

public boolean textDisplayedInPage(String text){
    WebElement element = null;
    try{
        element =getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'"+text+"')]"));
    }catch (Exception e){}
    if(element != null){
        return true;
    };
    return false;
}
```

[image]

problem is the textDisplayedInPage() method doesn't work and selenium finds the element on the first screen even though it's not displayed yet and breaks the loop. I have tried few answers that I found of similar issues here but all fails to deliver what's displayed.  Any insight on how to capture or verify displayed text of a scrollable element would help.

Comment: If all you need is a screenshot there are other ways to do that... if you need to know if it's offscreen you can execute javascript... see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport

Answer (score 1):

When Selenium looks for an element it checks inside DOM-tree and even though you can't see whole text yet it's in there. If you need to retrieve and verify some text than probably **element.getText()** would be enough for this, but if you absolutely need to take screenshots thеn you can use **JavaScriptExecutor** and some scrolling down JS code:

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 js.executeScript("document.getElementById(id_attribute_value).scrollHeight;", "");
```